# Binomial distibution with mean 0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

I give the following context. Test hypothesis $H_0:p=p_o$ for Bernoulli distributed random variable $X$, with parameter $p$ and samples $X_i$. For estimate $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_i$, $n\hat{p}$ is a binomially distributed random variable with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$. Thus, $\hat{p}$ is binomially distributed with mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)/n$.

The random variable $T=\frac{\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}-p_0)}{\sqrt{p_0*(1-p_0)}}$ is binomially distributed with mean $p-p_0$ and variance $1$. Then, under $H_0:p=p_0$ it is binomially distributed with mean 0 and variance 1.

Can you give me an intuition or interpretation what it means that a binomially distributed randon variable ($T$ under $H_0$ in this case) has a mean of 0. Especially what it means when we look at the definition of the binomial distribution and the formula for the mean: $np$.

Comment: $T$ is not a Binomial variable, but the standardisation of the Binomial variable $n\hat p$.

Comment: That makes sense. However, what made me come up with that question is, that I found the following notation:
$T=\frac{\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}-p_0)}{\sqrt{p_0*(1-p_0)}}\stackrel{H_0}{\sim}Bi(0,1,n)
$

Comment: And I think i do not know exactly what is meant by standardizing a binomially distributed RV.

Comment: Notation: wrong. Standardised rv: please google it.

Comment: @Joe Not everything you can "find" is going to be correct/make sense.

Comment: Standardization is subtracting expected value and the dividing by the standard deviation. In my case, this is subtracting $np$ and dividing by $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, which yields T, which is approximately N(0,1) distributed for large n. However, then I do not understand why it is not also binomially distributed according to the above argument.

Comment: The source is here and the author uses it in many other texts[link](https://books.google.de/books?id=G0_HxBubGAwC&pg=PA695&lpg=PA695&dq=aris+spanos+%22Bi(0,+1%22&source=bl&ots=4DFUr_d-0a&sig=ACfU3U14bEWG-IkQmarx-i6vGNHZShKAGQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW1-Gi4P3mAhWMwqYKHaskAUUQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=aris%20spanos%20%22Bi(0%2C%201%22&f=false)

Comment: One of the joys of really *studying* a good textbook is to find the typographical errors that inevitably occur: that is an excellent way to assess your understanding of the material.